# Is it possible to change the defaultProps on a react-native TextInput?

Tags: react-native

I am using a lot of react-native TextInputs in my app and I am manually changing the selectionColor of each one by adding:

```
<TextInput
  //various settings
  selectionColor={white}
  //more settings
 />
```

into every TextInput. After some investigation into how I could change this globally I discovered defaultProps and I believe something like

```
TextInput.defaultProps={selectionColor: 'white'}
```

should be enough to change it once and for all. However I'm not sure that I have the syntax right as putting this code inside my first TextInput does not work. Additionally I'm not sure where the best place in my app would be to change these defaultProps would be, as perhaps doing this change in the first TextInput that appears is the wrong spot.

Has anyone had experience changing the defaultProps of a react-native TextInput like this before?

Comment: why don't you set a <MyTextInput/> by yourself??

Comment: Thanks, that idea works too :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap around your TextInput with your own component and you will have full control of the default props that can be passed into your component and down into the TextInput.

This is also a recommended approach when using UI libraries since things can change and while wrapping components you can switch the inner implementation as you please without having to make small changes all over your app.